# MyBatis SQL Builder Class LIKE with %

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

we have a Spring Boot Project with MyBatis, in the project we choose to use the SQL Builder to keep all SQL dynamic and generated from the provider class that correspond to the function, but we have a problem trying to use the 'LIKE' in a 'WHERE' clause, because of the business i can only tell you the problem with example, so we have the following provider (it is a example):

```
public class ExampleProvider {
   public static String select (ExampleModel model) {
      return new SQL() {{
         SELECT("ID, NAME, PHONE");
         FROM("PERSON");
         WHERE("PHONE LIKE '%#{phone}%'");
      }}.toString();
   }
}
```

if with use this code we get this result

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='phone', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.String, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Could not set parameter at position 1 (values was '4241234567')
Query - conn:33652(M)  - "SELECT ID, NAME, PHONE
FROM PERSON
WHERE (PHONE LIKE '%?%')"
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:92) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:440) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.selectList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:223) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:147) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:80) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:144) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:85) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.buscar(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at ve.com.megasoft.snp.repositorio.TestInterfazBdTransaccion.test(TestInterfazBdTransaccion.java:140) ~[test-classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675) [junit-platform-commons-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209) ~[.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='phone', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.String, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Could not set parameter at position 1 (values was '4241234567')
Query - conn:33652(M)  -"SELECT ID, NAME, PHONE
FROM PERSON
WHERE (PHONE LIKE '%?%')"
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.defaults.DefaultParameterHandler.setParameters(DefaultParameterHandler.java:89) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.parameterize(PreparedStatementHandler.java:94) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.parameterize(RoutingStatementHandler.java:64) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:88) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:62) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:324) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:83) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:147) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:426) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.4.jar:2.0.4]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #1 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Could not set parameter at position 1 (values was '4241234567')
Query - conn:33652(M)  - "SELECT ID, NAME, PHONE
FROM PERSON
WHERE (PHONE LIKE '%?%')"
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:71) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.defaults.DefaultParameterHandler.setParameters(DefaultParameterHandler.java:87) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    ... 88 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not set parameter at position 1 (values was '4241234567')
Query - conn:33652(M)  - "SELECT ID, NAME, PHONE
FROM PERSON
WHERE (PHONE LIKE '%?%')"
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getSqlException(ExceptionMapper.java:278) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientSidePreparedStatement.setParameter(ClientSidePreparedStatement.java:474) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.5.4.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.BasePrepareStatement.setString(BasePrepareStatement.java:1385) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.5.4.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setString(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger.invoke(PreparedStatementLogger.java:67) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.setString(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.StringTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter(StringTypeHandler.java:31) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.StringTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter(StringTypeHandler.java:26) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:69) ~[mybatis-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
    ... 89 common frames omitted
```

it is probably something wrong in my end but i can put my finger in what it is wrong

Comment: See this [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-code-an-sql-like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to provide it. MyBatis will take it.
The syntax should be like this:

```
WHERE("PHONE LIKE '#{phone}'");
```

Below line is working fine with XML syntax.

```
<if test="fname != null">AND FNAME LIKE #{fname}</if>
```

As you are writing the query in Java, so try this "%1212%" (append % sign to value itself) and then set it to query.

Comment: OK, if a do that the Query don't work as we wanted, because of the use of "%".

Comment: Ok.... In that case you have to append the % to values itself I guess. LIke '%12345%' ... I have used MyBatis and with the XML configuration where the mentioned thing working fine. Edited my answer as well.